# C# REST Api always return 401 status code when i am calling API by HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am working with Nasdaq Fund Network Data Service first time. i am calling their one of the API where passing user id,pwd and access key but always getting 401 status code. i am not able to figure out what is wrong in my http call. please some one have a look at the code and tell me where i made the mistake for which i am getting 401 status code instead of right response.

here is my sample code where i could not share actual credentials and access key.
giving the code

```
string url = "sample url";
Uri u = new Uri(url);

string username = "test1";
string password = "test2";
string accessKey = "myaccesskey";

var payload = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  {"username", username},
  {"password", password},
  { "accessKey", accessKey}
};

string strPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
//HttpContent c = new StringContent(strPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpContent c = new StringContent(strPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var response = string.Empty;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = u,
        Content = c
    };

    var result = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response = result.StatusCode.ToString();
    }
}
```

### This Error i am getting

> {StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Check Username/Password or Access
> Key', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {
> Pragma: no-cache   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN   Cache-Control:
> no-cache   Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 11:55:36 GMT   Content-Length: 0
> Expires: -1 }}

Comment: If you are getting 401, you definetelly miss to add properties like contentType etc. Have you got same error in Postman etc. as well ? Are you sure about TLS as well ?

Comment: TLS or without TLS getting same error.

Comment: now i added content type `HttpContent c = new StringContent(strPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` but still getting 401

Comment: I think the best way before doing it on code is to try it on postman if it works using the credentials you have. It is easier to do things if you know the credentials and the URL you're connecting are correct and working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in order to extract the JWT token you receive as a response.

```
    var url = "https://nfn.nasdaq.com/servicecall/tempsession";

    var formDataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "username", "test1"},
        { "password", "test2"},
        { "accessKey", "myaccesskey"}
    };

    var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formDataDictionary);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var responseBody = JObject.Parse(result);
        var accessToken = responseBody["data']"].Value<string>();
    }
```

Comment: still getting 401 after using your changed code.

Comment: @RameshDutta Are you passing in the right username, password and accesskey? Test it in Postman. Unable to help further like this.

Comment: @RameshDutta so it's working now? Please post the solution if so.

Comment: sorry i can't expose credentials & accesskey.

Comment: @RameshDutta that seems obvious, but you can share the solution without exposing anything sensitive. So please do.

Comment: see my first code posted which i used with right pwd and it works.